# Crochet hook size switch mid project

Tags: crocheting, crochet-hooks

I lost my crochet hook . Size 3.5 mm . If I switch to a size 3mm will it make a huge different in my afghan ?

Answer (score 3):

Not a *huge* difference, but certainly a *noticable* difference.

The size difference between a 3 and 3,5 hook is just half a millimeter. The size difference in the stitches you make with both hooks may be even smaller than that, but I think it's unlikely that you manage to make your stitches exactly the same size.

So let's assume each stitch gets only 0.1 mm smaller after switching to a smaller hook. If you crochet 50 stitches over the width of your afghan, you lose 5 cm (2 inches) in width. If you crochet 100 stitches over the entire width, you lose 10 cm (4 inches).

Of course you can compensate by deliberately making your stitches bigger. But I still think that you will get a visible line at the part where you switched hook size because your tension will change in that area.

Comment: To substitute and keep the stitch size the same you need to be a very experienced crocherer and all of those I know do have plenty of hooks in the popular sizes. My lifehack answer would be to ask around, especially older females might have a spare.